# Perforce changelists - is it mandatory?

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to understand if I must use a changelist when I checkout a file?

I'm consider to use Perforce (haven't tried it yet). My question refers to its methodology.

Answer (score 5):

There's a default changelist where things go if you don't specifically choose another changelist for it, but it has limitations like not being able to shelve files.  If you're spending a significant amount of time on a change, it's usually very useful to create a numbered changelist with your eventual submit message right away.  It's also handy to put temporary changes you don't intend to submit into their own changelist.  It's a similar workflow to the way people use multiple local branches in a DVCS.